# Get MAX Date is not working in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to get the max date from table but when I do this in PHP, it doesn't show any results.

```
$max_date = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(periodo) FROM mytable") or die (mysql_error());
$max_date = mysql_fetch_assoc($max_date);
$max_date = $max_date['periodo'];
```

It's not displaying any errors just doesn't showing something, but when I do that query directly in PHPMyAdmin it works, I have no idea what I'm doing wrong

[image]

Comment: query should be `SELECT MAX(periodo) as 'periodo' FROM mytable`

Comment: `mysql_` functions? Why? These functions have been deprecated for a long time....

Comment: Alternatively,  `$max_date = $max_date['MAX(periodo)'];` would work too.

Comment: @kamalpal I didn't know this...so when I use a function with a specific field always is required an alias?

Comment: usually when you have used aggregate function on fields, or when you needed

Comment: The problem is that MySQL, by default, gives the name "MAX(periodo)" to the result column. So, in fact, you can access to it with `$max_data['MAX(periodo)']`. But it's no too much pretty ;)

Comment: @kamalpal thank you so much, and to you guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @kamal pal said in his comment, you need to provide an alias for your column:

`SELECT MAX(periodo) AS 'periodo' FROM mytable`

Comment: You don't need to provide an alias. You just have to use the correct name, which is usually easier when you provide an alias.

Comment: And it does not need to be in single quotes

Comment: It does not need it, but I think that is a good practice. Specially to not forgot it when you wan to give a name with spaces ;)